# Symfony restrict page access to a group of people

Tags: symfony, security

I have pages like 'localhost/articles/show/id', representing the article details with the corresponding id.
I'd like to restrict the page access to a group of people.

In my database, each User belongs to a Family and each Article belongs to a Family as well.
And I want the users to be able to access article informations only if the article has been created by the family that the user is member of.

I could just verify manually by comparing the article's family to the current user family with some request in the Controller before rendering but I would to duplicated this code for every page like '/show/id', '/edit/id', ... Yet I'd like to know if there is a more beautiful way of doing it with symfony, something like 'every page that refers to a specific Article (/edit/id, /show/id and so on so forth) use a specific class to verify if the user is a member of the Family that created the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the thing you're looking for is Voter.

> Security voters are the most granular way of checking permissions. All voters are
> called each time you use the isGranted() method on Symfony’s authorization
> checker or call denyAccessUnlessGranted() in a controller.

see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

```
// src/Security/PostVoter.php

//....
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;

class ArticleVoter extends Voter
{
    // these strings are just invented: you can use anything
    const VIEW = 'view';
    const EDIT = 'edit';

    /**
     * return true if the voter support your entity ($subject) type
     */
    protected function supports(string $attribute, $subject)
    {
        // if the attribute isn't one we support, return false
        if (!in_array($attribute, [self::VIEW, self::EDIT])) {
            return false;
        }

        // only vote on `Article` objects
        if (!$subject instanceof Article) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            // the user must be logged in; if not, deny access
            return false;
        }

        // you know $subject is a Article object, thanks to `supports()`
        /** @var Article $post */
        $article = $subject;

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW:
                return $this->canView($article, $user);
            case self::EDIT:
                return $this->canEdit($article, $user);
        }

        throw new \LogicException('This code should not be reached!');
    }

    private function canView(Article $article, User $user)
    {
        //Return true if user can view article, false otherwise 
    }

    private function canEdit(Article $article, User $user)
        //Return true if user can edit article, false otherwise
    }
}
```

Voters are used when you call $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(String $actionName, $entity) from your controllers. this method will throws an exception if a voter that support your $entity type and your $actionName return false.

```
// src/Controller/ArticleController.php
// ...

class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/article/{id}", name="article_show")
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        
        $article = ...;

        // check for "view" access: calls all voters
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', $article);

        // ...do your stuff
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/article/{id}/edit", name="article_edit")
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $article = ...;

        // check for "edit" access: calls all voters
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('edit', $article);

        // ... do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)